# Find index of GameObject in array of GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity

In my script, i have declared an array of GameObjects like this:

```
public GameObject[] go;ld object name. `String temp;`
```

Also, i have a temporary variable to ho
Then, i assigned objects to elements in Inspector.

I'm using Raycasting to find which object was clicked. Block of code for handling Raycast:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity,layerMask);

        if (hit) {
            temp=hit.collider.gameObject.name;
            index=ArrayList.IndexOf(go,GameObject.Find (temp));

                }
```

Ray casting works well. It will print object name if i insert a Debug.Log. However, what i want to do is, find the GameObject's index in the array "go".
I need this index because i have another boolean array isSelect[] which, has a property that needs to be set to true when the corresponding GameObject is selected.

With the IndexOf code above, i get the following error:

```
An object reference is required to access non-static member `System.Collections.ArrayList.IndexOf(object)
```

What changes do i need to make to this code?

Comment: fyi doing GameObject.Find() here is pretty wasteful, since you already *had* a reference to the gameobject. That's what hit.collider.gameobject is, no need to search for it by name

Comment: You are right i should instead try something like ' index=System.Array.IndexOf(go,hit.collider.GameObject);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after i replaced

```
index=ArrayList.IndexOf(go,GameObject.Find (temp));
```

with

```
index=System.Array.IndexOf(go,GameObject.Find (temp));
```

Comment: So in other words the returned object is an Array not an ArrayList. The names are similar (indeed, the object's *are* similar) but they aren't the same.